# Accessing user name from another model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following relationships in my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :tutor, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages
end

class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :tutors
end
```

In my messages index view, I want to make something like an inbox where the user names associated to that message are displayed. I tried in my console doing Message.first:

```
 Message.first   Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM
 "messages" ORDER BY "messages"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  => #<Message id: 1,
 subject: "some subject", body: "and some body", created_at:
 "2013-09-01 13:09 :57", updated_at: "2013-09-01 13:09:57", user_id: 1,
 recipient_id: 2>
```

If I do `Message.first.users`, I get:

```
 Message.first.users   Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM
 "messages" ORDER BY "messages"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  => nil
```

I basically want to get the `username` from the `recipient_id`. Did I set this up incorrectly? Am I supposed to do a join or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `belongs_to` association declaration in `Message` model is incorrect.  Please reference "[The belongs_to Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association)" for further details.

So, updating your `Message` model should fix the issue:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  # use singular :user and :tutor here

  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :tutor
end
```

Then you would query the user of your message using:

```
Message.first.user
```

Comment: OK this works for Message.first.user. However, as I (poorly) explained, I am looking to get the user name from `recipient_id`, which is the other user. Is doing something like this incorrect: `User.find(Message.first.recipient_id, select: 'first_name, last_name')` ?

Comment: So, I know this looks horrible but I think this is what I'm alluding to: `User.find(Tutor.find(Message.first.recipient_id))`

Comment: Actually that doesn't seem to work properly. This does however: `Tutor.find(message.recipient_id).user`....wow, that's a mess...